# How to get a value from application.properties in Spring Boot with a component in a service to encrypt a property in a entity

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I call the method *llaveCom.getName()* I always get a null, I don't know why

Code of component"

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("app")
public class LlaveCompo {

private String name;
private String llave;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getLlave() {
    return llave;
}

public void setLlave(String llave) {
    this.llave = llave;
}
}
```

The values that I want to get
**application.properties**

```
app.name=hola

app.llave=fE3tTFvoRd#PYDLoXdIq4ytJJP#ym%Mw
```

Service from I inject the component:

```
@Autowired
private LlaveCompo llaveCom;

private static final String AES = "AES";
@Value("app.llave")
private  String secret = "fE3tTFvoRd#PYDLoXdIq4ytJJP#ym%Mw" ;
private final Key key;
private final Cipher cipher;

public CryptoService() throws Exception{
    System.out.println(llaveCom.getName());
    System.out.println("llave: "+llaveC);
    key = new SecretKeySpec(secret.getBytes(), AES);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
}
```

logs that describe the errors:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServic': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cryptoService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cryptoService' defined in file [C:\Users\ECE-LD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PruebaCripto2\target\classes\com\example\PruebaCripto\services\CryptoService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.PruebaCripto.services.CryptoService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userServic': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'cryptoService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cryptoService' defined in file [C:\Users\ECE-LD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PruebaCripto2\target\classes\com\example\PruebaCripto\services\CryptoService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.PruebaCripto.services.CryptoService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cryptoService' defined in file [C:\Users\ECE-LD\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PruebaCripto2\target\classes\com\example\PruebaCripto\services\CryptoService.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.PruebaCripto.services.CryptoService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.example.PruebaCripto.services.CryptoService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

Comment: maybe @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app") and @EnableConfigurationProperties(LlaveCompo.class) in Main class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use constructor injection. And because you already injection Llaveompo you don't need to have @Value for the secret.

```
private final LlaveCompo llaveCom;

private static final String AES = "AES";
private final Key key;
private final Cipher cipher;

public CryptoService(LlaveCompo llaveCom) throws Exception{
    this.llaveCom = llaveCom;
    System.out.println(llaveCom.getName());
    System.out.println("llave: "+llaveC);

    key = new SecretKeySpec(llaveCom.getLlave().getBytes(), AES);
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES);
}
```